# Minimum required plugins and settings for babel and parcel to be able to handle Symbol.iterator and for of

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, parceljs

I have the following toy program to learn about es6 features. Using Parcel and babel. What are the minimum plugins requirements to get `Symbol.iterator` and `for of` to work. I tried combining multiple plugins but no success. The only solution I found was

```
let array = [1, 2, 3];

 array[Symbol.iterator] = function(){
      let nextValue = 10;
           return {
              next(){
                 nextValue ++;
                 return {
                     done: nextValue > 14,
                     value: nextValue
                     };
              }
           };
       };

  for (let element of array) {
      console.log(element);
  }
```

The only solution I found for my .babelrc was:

```
      {
         "presets": [
             ["env", {
                "targets": {
                "browsers": ["last 2 Chrome versions"]
                }
               }]
              ]
        }
```

But it is not really satisfactory, I would like to know which plugins really handle those.